# How define schema SEO tags in the head of next.js 13.4 app route project

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to put advanced schema SEO markup in the HEAD of a next.js 13.4 project, using the app. routes.

Using the HEAD component didn't worked, I only managed to put the code in the body, which feels kinda dirty.

Hello,

I'm trying to use Next.js 13.4 for a blog. However I'm not sure how I could define my SEO schema markup in it. I followed the recommandation here : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata (without the dynamic aspect), with something like this :

layout.js :

```
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'


const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
  viewport: {
    width: 'device-width',
    initialScale: 1,
    maximumScale: 1,
  },
  
}


const jsonLd = {
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "BlogPosting",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "@id": "https://www.example.com/blog/blog-post-url"
  },
  }

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <script
        type="application/ld+json"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: JSON.stringify(jsonLd) }}
        />
        <div  className= "container">{children}</div>
        </body>
    </html>
  )
}
  )
}
```

It worked, however I feel it's kinda dirty and am bothered by the fact that my json is not in the head part.

Should I worry less ? Do you know how to put these informations in the head part ? I tried with the "head" component :

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Head>
        {/* Add additional meta tags or stylesheets here */}
        <script
        type="application/ld+json"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: JSON.stringify(jsonLd) }}
        />
      </Head>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <div  className= "container">{children}</div>
        </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

, but it didn't worked.